# Look up property owner using ROLL number (Ontario)

Tags: data-request, real-estate, canada

I have the tax ROLL number (aka ARN - Active Rolle Number) of a specific property/parcel in Ontario, Canada. I want to determine who the owner of the parcel is. (For what it's worth, I also have the municpal address and spatial location too.)

How can I look up the property owner using the ROLL number?

Are there any free or paid resources where I can do that online?

---

**Edit:**

*An example of something similar - look up a **PIN** instead of a **ROLL** number:*

I can use the steps on this page: https://www.ihunterapp.com/using-ihunter-and-onland-to-find-property-information/.

1. Subscribe to [iHunter](https://web.ihunterapp.com/) for ~$40 CAD per year. The iHunter map has polygons that have parcel PIN numbers.
2. From there, enter the PIN number into [OnLand](https://www.onland.ca/) to download a PDF that has the property owner info (costs ~$30 CAD).

   - As an alternative to using OnLand, I think the same thing can be done using [Teranet Express](https://www.teranetexpress.ca/csp/) . It seems to cost ~$30 CAD too, the same as OnLand, so I'm not sure if there is a benefit to one or the other.

Using those steps, I can look up the property owner using parcel's **PIN** number. Which works, but isn't what I'm looking for. I want to look up the **ROLL** number instead -- since that's the information I have on hand.